# Is it possible to custimize Pycharm project setting folder .idea

Tags: pycharm

I think this is increasing to be a problem for people who work on multiple machines with Pycharm. I work on my MacBook Pro when I travel daily and then go back to windows when I'm at home. I leave the files on Dropbox as it's not really a project for git. But whenever I switch machines, the project settings will be overridden (for example, the interpreter won't be found ... because they are at different locations in different machines.).

I googled around and read a few pages on JetBrain but not to no avail. Anyone knows if there is a way to tell PyCharm to look for .idea2 instead .idea.

I know there are funky ways to hack it (like deselect sync folders) but I am working on many small projects like this. It'd be ideal to have a better solution. I'm also thinking about setting up a remote interpreter on both machines (Docker). Maybe it'll fix the problem. I'll keep you posted.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using `Settings Repository` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/synchronizing-and-sharing-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm stops complaint since I switch to a remote interpreter.